# Put two pictures above one another within one sub float / reference problem

Tags: captions, subfloats, minipage

I was going through some crazy hoops to get minipage and subfloat work nicely (?) together, only to find out in the very end that I screwed up the figure references.

I have a figure with two subfloats, one on the left one on the right. The left is composed of two graphics above one another. That last fact causes big trouble because I cannot use `\\` or `\newline` in `subfloat` alone. So I build a `minipage` around it, but then the `subfloat` cannot *contain* the `minipage`, so I reversed their nesting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
% note: the following packages are _givens_, I cannot change them at this point
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang,small]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

As shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:right}...

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\begin{minipage}{0.39\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=0 0 0 -70mm]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}\\[2mm]%
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=0 -60mm 0 0]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1901m.jpg}%
\\\centering \subfloat[Left]{\hspace{0.9\textwidth}}\label{fig:left}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.58\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=-2mm 0 0 0]{figures/Zelle148ScoreCut.pdf}%
\\\centering \subfloat[Right]{\hspace{1\textwidth}}\label{fig:right}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Full caption}
\label{fig:both}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, I get errors

> Package caption Warning: \label before \caption on input line 20.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:right' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
>
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

The figure result looks as I want:

[image]

But the reference in the text just shows up as "??" instead of "1b".

Comment: I tried to replace `subfig` with `subcaption` which I read is recommended. I didn't disturb the rest of the thesis I have formatted so far, so I'm ok to make this change if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the following fulfill your purpose? It comes without any trim or anything like that. The basic idea here is to create a two column table, both columns centered. The left column is again a single column table with two rows, where you put your *Left* pictures one above another. The right column is again a table, with only one row, which contains your *Right* picture. You align the last two tables at bottom. You will want to tweak the column widths. Here I have used `0.4\textwidth`, but slightly wider should also be alright.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang,small]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

As shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:right}...

\begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[c]{cc}
    \subfloat[Left]{\label{fig:left}%
      \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}\\[2mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1901m.jpg}
      \end{tabular}}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
      \subfloat[Right]{\label{fig:right}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/Zelle148ScoreCut.pdf}}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Full caption}
  \label{fig:both}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, too. Didn't know you can put `tabular` inside `subfloat` when you can't put `minipage` there.

Answer (score 0):

Using `subcaption` indeed seems to solve my problem. I kind of combines `minipage` and `subfloat`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang,small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} % !!!
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

As shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:right}...

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\begin{subfigure}{0.39\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=0 0 0 -70mm]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}\\[2mm]%
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=0 -60mm 0 0]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1901m.jpg}%
\caption{Left}\label{fig:left}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.58\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim=-2mm 0 0 0]{figures/Zelle148ScoreCut.pdf}%
\caption{Right}\label{fig:right}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Full caption}
\label{fig:both}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Does anyone have a better solution than using negative `trim` hackery to achieve the vertical centering of left and right side, while keeping sub captions on the same vertical position?