# Arrange three images

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I need to arrange three figures in a two column document as follows

[image: figure arrangement]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Comments**

You did not tell us about the individual/main captions and/or references. I decided to throw that in as well.

**Basic Idea**

1. For a two column document use the option `[twocolumn]` with the `\documentclass`.
2. Create a two column table (outer table). Put another single column table in the first column. Put the first two images (A and B) as the two rows of the inner table. Put the third image (B) in the second column of the outer table.
3. Use   `subcaption` to take care of captions and labels. (This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148445/14103) helps.)

**The Solution**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text only

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
  \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{A.png}
        \caption{A.}
        \label{fig:A}
      \end{subfigure}\\
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{B.png}
        \caption{B.}
        \label{fig:B}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{C.png}
      \caption{C.}
      \label{fig:C}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{tabular}
  \label{fig:ABC}
  \caption{A, B and C.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

**Further Tweaking**

Change the `0.4\columnwidth`s to tweak image sizes. Watch for overfull boxes.

Comment: What's the advantage of using tabular instead of minipage?

Comment: @skan Nothing specific. Depends on the situation you are using and how you want to control the placement.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to involve two different parts:

1. How to create a two-column document
2. How to arrange the figures in two columns

The answer to 1. is to use the `twocolumn` option in the `article` class.

The answer to 2. is to use a `minipage` environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=4cm]{triangle}
\\[3mm]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=4cm]{triangle}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=83mm]{triangle}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code to generate the `triangle.pdf` file is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green!20] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `example-image-a` which comes bundled with `mwe` package. There is also `-b` and `-c` in addition to `-a` above. Further, there is no need of loading `mwe` if you just want to use these images like `\includegraphics{example-image-b}`. :-)