# Two images in one line

Tags: graphics, subfloats, columns

How can set two images in one line without using a table, but having a caption and a label for each image? Besides image one should be labeled Figure 1 and the second figure with Figure 2.
Therefore I want the following construction:

```
**************     *******************
*            *     *                 *
*            *     *                 *
**************     *******************
Figure 1: Caption  Figure 2: Caption
```

I tried already subfigure:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfigure[caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Screenshots/step1.png}}
\subfigure[caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.41\linewidth]{boundingbox.eps}}
\end{figure}
```

But this made (a) and (b) and one number for both figures.

Furthermore I tried:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{7cm}}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/step1.png}
\label{fig:stepone}
\caption{caption one}
\end{center} & \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{boundingbox.eps}
\label{fig:steptwo}
\caption{caption two}
\end{center} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

But here the the columns are labeld with Table 1 and Table 2.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side, here you should find the answer.

Comment: @Umz Thats not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ Irgendw Pointer, did you see Gonzalo Medina's solution with the minipage?

Comment: No I have seen only the first images. Thank that works

Comment: @IrgendwPointer Did you see [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148438/14103)?

Comment: @MMA I didnt find this link. But it was what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Depending how you'd like the other figures in your document to be presented, you could simply redefine the caption for the `subfigures` as follows (based on [this website](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_captions)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfig}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens, labelsep=colon}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \subfloat[caption]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Screenshots/step1.png}%
        }%
    \subfloat[caption]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.41\linewidth]{boundingbox.eps}%
        }%
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That won't work for me. I get the following error: No counter 'subfigure@save' defined. \subfloat

Comment: Can you compile the MWE? When I look for the error message on google I find that it seems to happen when you use `subcaption` and `subfig`together: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=23576